# How to control log level of deno/std/log module from command line?

Tags: deno

for example, how to log out debug info `Hello world` for

```js
import * as log from "https://deno.land/std@0.173.0/log/mod.ts";

// Simple default logger out of the box. You can customize it
// by overriding logger and handler named "default", or providing
// additional logger configurations. You can log any data type.
log.debug("Hello world");
log.info(123456);
log.warning(true);
log.error({ foo: "bar", fizz: "bazz" });
log.critical("500 Internal server error");
```

from https://deno.land/std@0.173.0/log/mod.ts

I tried `deno run -A --log-level=DEBUG` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for example, how to log out debug info `Hello world` for...

Below is an example of how you can configure all levels of logging to the console at `"DEBUG"` and above.

The module at [`https://deno.land/std@0.174.0/log/mod.ts`](https://deno.land/std@0.174.0/log/mod.ts) includes some example code that looks just like the lines in your question (on [lines 97-153](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/blob/0.174.0/log/mod.ts#L97-L153) in the file) — it is what I used as a basis for the code below.

`so-75244033.ts`:

```ts
import * as log from "https://deno.land/std@0.174.0/log/mod.ts";

// This could be read from an environment variable or parsed from a CLI argument:
const LOG_LEVEL = "DEBUG";

log.setup({
  handlers: {
    console: new log.handlers.ConsoleHandler(LOG_LEVEL),
  },
  loggers: {
    default: {
      level: LOG_LEVEL,
      handlers: ["console"],
    },
  },
});

// Simple default logger out of the box. You can customize it
// by overriding logger and handler named "default", or providing
// additional logger configurations. You can log any data type.
log.debug("Hello world");
log.info(123456);
log.warning(true);
log.error({ foo: "bar", fizz: "bazz" });
log.critical("500 Internal server error");
```

In the terminal:

```txt
% deno --version
deno 1.30.0 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.9.194.5
typescript 4.9.4
```

```txt
% deno run so-75244033.ts
DEBUG Hello world
INFO 123456
WARNING true
ERROR {"foo":"bar","fizz":"bazz"}
CRITICAL 500 Internal server error
```

Comment: That way, I have to modify source code to change log level. It doesn't make sense. Same code should be used for both development and production environments.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75244033/how-to-control-log-level-of-deno-std-log-module-from-command-line/75244507?noredirect=1#comment132777259_75244507) @WenpinCHOU You need not use string literals in your source code. Deno can read values from [environment variables](https://deno.land/manual@v1.30.0/basics/env_variables) and [parse CLI arguments](https://deno.land/std@0.174.0/flags/mod.ts). I added a comment in the example code to address that concern.

Comment: I was looking for default CLI argument like "--log-level", now that I understood that there's no such default option.